# Reuse Put in HBase client?

Tags: hbase, object-pooling

When put a new row to HBase, it is needed to create a new `Put` instance and call `add(byte [] family, byte [] qualifier, long ts, byte [] value)` to add data, which will create a `KeyValue` instance. If there are lots of put operations, lots of `Put` and `KeyValue` will be created. It triggers GC frequently.

Is there any way to re-use `Put` and `KeyValue`? If so, I can use an ObjectPool to stable the memory usage instead of allocating memory which will be GCed very soon.